# justinmind prototyper comes with a complex code. can we do backend program using Django, since we have to speparate the staticfiles and templates?

Tags: django-templates, justinmind

django needs the static files and templates are to be in their separate folders. But the prototypes created using the justinmind prototyper comes with multiple html files and complex structure. Is there any method to simplify the structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use their api to extract the information the way you want:
http://www.justinmind.com/plugin-market/create-plugin